# Who is 'Ebinichibel' mentioned in the Borgia Map?

Tags: europe, middle-east, maps, cartography, folklore

[Wikipedia:BorgiaMap](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borgia_map) page gives this detail,

> The Borgia map includes a legend referring to Ebinichibel, who is described as "the Saracen Ethiopian king with his dog-headed people".

Is this related to any historical/legendary figure?

I don't know of any Ethiopians who ruled Saracens or vice versa, except [Abraha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraha) of Axumite Kingdom who ruled a small portion of Yemen for a brief period.

Searching this term just gives links to the same map with the same detail.

Comment: Various early travel writers believed that [dog-headed men](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cynocephaly) existed. I think [Ethiopian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aethiopia) here indicates 'African' or 'Black' rather than someone from modern Ethiopia.

Comment: [Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/26786)  All of the mentions of Ebinichibel I can find refer to the Borgia map.  This may be our only record of the myth, other than as KateBunting mentions

Comment: [Saracen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saracen) was at one point just the word used to describe anyone adhering to the Islamic faith.

Comment: [Pliny the Elder](http://www.philipharland.com/Blog/2022/11/indians-ethiopians-and-others-pliny-the-elder-on-unbelievable-peoples-first-century-ce/) writes about dog-headed people somewhere in India or Ethiopia, though from context it is more likely that India is meant.

Comment: @KateBunting It'd be odd to use Ethiopian as a reference for 'Black'; why not Abyssinian (which I believe was the more common word at the time in Europe) or Nubian?

Comment: @Jan The Tartar Relation, by a 'Bridia', in 1247 AD, also mentions dog-faced people. But his report is on the Mongols, as a Franciscan emissary in the court of Batu Khan.

Comment: Tracing the citations from Wikipedia leads to Harley & Woodward's _The History Of Cartography_ (1987), [p. 332, note 226](https://archive.org/details/the-history-of-cartography-volume-1-cartography-in-prehistoric-ancient-and-medi/page/332/mode/1up): it gives the exact quote "Ebinichibel rex est sarracenos ethiopicos cum populo suo habiens caninam" and cites "[Almagià, _Vaticana_](https://www.worldcat.org/title/monumenta-cartographica-vaticana/oclc/2235464), **1**:27–29 and plate XI (note 83)." Sadly at that point the trail leaves the Internet, AFAICT.

Comment: Samid - see the link I provided to the article 'Aethiopia', section 'Etymology'.

Answer (score 3):

John Block Friedman in *The Monstrous Races in Medieval Art and Thought*, Syracuse 2020, p.67 (via google books) treats it as a fictional name (in a league with stuff from the Alexander romance) and claims that Ebinichibel is a distorted transliteration of the Arabic "Banu Kalb", "sons of a dog". Which one may or may not find entirely convincing, especially regarding the relative positions of the "l" and the "b". But it certainly does look somewhat plausible.

There actually was an Arabic tribe called [Banu Kalb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banu_Kalb) in the early Middle Ages, but it does not seem that there is an obvious relation.